# Sql server 2008 R2 installation fails with Error: 17204

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Sql server 2008 R2 installation fails with the below error message in the log message,

This is a part of the sql server log

> Starting up database 'msdb'. Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
>   e:\sql10_main_t.obj.x86fre\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf
>   for file number 1.  OS error: 21(failed to retrieve text for this
>   error. Reason: 1815).

Has anyone come across such an issue. Please help on how to resolve this issue.

EDIT: the sql server error log can be found at http://pastebin.com/TED7vJWX

EDIT:
This is the latest log,
2012-09-20 14:34:29.74 spid6s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.

2012-09-20 14:34:29.78 spid6s      The resource database build version is 10.50.1600. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2012-09-20 14:34:30.51 spid6s      Error: 15209, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2012-09-20 14:34:30.51 spid6s      An error occurred during encryption.

Same as before.

Comment: Did you modify the location of the system databases during installation?

Comment: No, I haven't modified any location.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue which has several causes:

1. The first thing to check is your permissions on local machine:
2. Are You a local Administrator?
3. Is there a group policy that might prevent you from installing \ debugging?

If these do not resolve the problem in your case, and you have verified the required permissions, please provide more info:

1. What parameters do you use during installation (beside the default ones)?
2. Which Edition of SQL Server are You installing?
3. Do You use Default instance name?
4. On which O/S are You installing?

EDIT:
Next steps: 
1. open the folder "`:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log`
2. Find a file named Detail.txt
3. This file has a complete log, You need to find the FIRST error that occured during installation.
4. Paste it here, only the part with the error.

EDIT:
Added Solution to comments, waiting to hear if the problem is solved

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I have checked, there are no issues with permissions.The installation is started with Admin privileges.
Below is the info you have asked for:
Parameters during installation:
/ACTION=INSTALL /UIMODE=AutoAdvance /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=<NAME> /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True" /NPENABLED=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=<Password>
Sql Server Version:Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) 
We are using a named instance.
OS-WindowsXP

Comment: It still might be a matter of security, please make sure You have Debug Rights as stated here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000257

Comment: Take a look at The group policy item  
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Debug  

If You are a member of local administrators group but the group is not a member of the debug group, installation will fail.

Comment: The Error Log You added is showing that SQL Server is trying to start and fails. That is because installation did not complete successfully, and did not get to the part where it sets the database path inside master database. Please post the log file "Detail.txt" from the folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log" (find the relevant subfolder for the last installation attempt)

Comment: I have added the error log from Detail.txt.

Comment: There is a possibility that the service account does not have permission to access the folder: "C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\Application Data\Microsoft\Protect " Please give full control permissions on "C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService" including subfolders to the LOCAL user "Network Service". After this is done You will have to uninstall SQL Server 2008R2 Express completely, and install it again. If the user already had permissions on the folder, or this did not solve the problem let me know. If this works - scream "yay" as loud as You can :)

Comment: In the user's machine there was no Protect folder, Though the path D:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\Application Data\Microsoft existed. PS, it is D: and not C:. I gave permissions on this folder to Network Service. But, it didn't work. I have added the latest error log. Please help.

Comment: Are You using NTFS or FAT storage?  
If You're using NTFS: try to create the folder (replace C with D if necessary, I hope this will help others as well so I'm sticking to defaults) "C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\Application Data\Microsoft\Protect" and give FULL CONTROL permission on it to the LOCAL USER "NETWORK SERVICE".  
Then do the whole thing again: complete uninstall, restart, install.  
If You use FAT storage let me know, it has a different solution.

Comment: The file system is NTFS. But this didnt work :(

Comment: Could NetworkService folder being in the D drive rather than C drive be the cause for the problem?

Comment: The folder being in D is not likely to cause the problem,  
Please Upload the complete "detail.txt" from the last installation attempt, I will try to see if we have missed something about the cause of the problem.  
In the worst case scenario we will have to recreate your system databases, but that is only as a last resort...

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? please let us know